# Azure Domain binding Issue

Tags: asp.net, azure

I bought a domain on Azure I hosted my application on the Azure portal. The problem I have it is not showing my app. but on sub-domain, my app is running correctly, but when I am trying to access main domain it is not working I know it is DNS issue. Can anyone help me out

```
http://www.coinunderpant.com/     --->Main Domain
http://agha.coinunderpant.com/      --- Subdomain
http://root.coinunderpant.com/
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that **www.coinunderpant.com** is also a subdomain, you should bind it to your app just like what you have done with **agha.coinunderpant.com**.

If you need **coinunderpant.com** point to your app, you should enable the A record mapping in the app.

[image]

You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain for more details.

Comment: can check the image I am getting SSL error nothing under "Private Certificate Thumbprint" coming

Comment: You need to Upload your SSL certificate first, you can follow this document(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl) to bind an existing ssl certificate. Here are the requirements for your certificate https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl#requirements-for-your-ssl-certificate.

Comment: If you’re Microsoft partner, I find a free channel to solve azure queries: aka.ms/devchat. They support online chat and email.”